# dhcpv6 returning bad subnet

Tags: linux, ipv6, router, dhcp

I have IPv6 on a linux machine and my network and it works. Now I want to set up DHCP for it. I set up the isc-dhcp-server and configured the subnet.

Another linux machine (both debian 7) acts as test-client and gets the IP, but not in the range configured, and, much worse, gets a /64 subnet and not a /80.

Since the IP pool available on the router is already a subset of the /64 assigned to another upstream-machine, I need a smaller subnet. I cannot allow it to be /64.

Config of dhcp server:

```
subnet6 2a01:4f8:202:6106:acda::/80 {
    range6  2a01:4f8:202:6106:acda:f000::/84;
    option dhcp6.name-servers 2a01:4f8:202:6106::2;
    prefix6 2a01:4f8:202:6106:acda:c000:: 2a01:4f8:202:6106:acda:f000:: /84;
}
```

ifconfig output on client:

```
debian@arm:~$ sudo ifconfig
[sudo] password for debian:
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:a0:30:ae:48:24
          inet addr:192.168.0.104  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::caa0:30ff:feae:4824/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a01:4f8:202:6106:acda:ff2f:452c:b7b5/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:201 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:18222 (17.7 KiB)  TX bytes:23159 (22.6 KiB)
          Interrupt:56
```

A windows-7 machine also connected does not get an IPv6 address at all.

config of the radvd on the server (in case it matters)

```
interface eth0 {
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    prefix 2a01:4f8:202:6106:acda::/80 {
        AdvOnLink on;
        AdvAutonomous on;
        AdvRouterAddr on;
    };
    route 2000::/3
    {
    };
};
```

What's wrong? Why is this not working? Is the bad subnet-size a bug in the server? Or the client?

Result of the bad subnet-size is that for example the nameserver, 2a01:4f8:202:6106::2 , in the 64-bit range, is not reachable. The client thinks it should be on the lan segment and tries to get the link-local IPv6 and the ethernet MAC of it and fails. It needs to go via the router. When I set the subnet manually to /80 everything works fine.

Comment: You do not want to break a /64 into smaller networks. See RFC 5375, IPv6 Unicast Address Assignment Considerations, "Using a subnet prefix length other than a /64 will break many features of IPv6..."

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks for that link. It looks like it is strongly recommended.

But, My provider only gives me one /64 range on my rental-server, and I set it up to forward a subrange of it to my site. I did not want to NAT as the address space should be sufficient.

The range from the provider is  2a01:4f8:202:6106::/64
I made a tunnel, in a tiny subnet, part of this, to forward packets to the /80 subrange (inside the /64, but not the tunnel's p2p net).
Therefore I cannot take the whole range. It would not leave an address for the remote machine itself.

Any suggestion on how to do this without NAT?

Comment: Also, if this proposal were the cause, the DHCP server should report error. Maybe I should try posting this to the isc dhcp server forum. There are other bugs in it too.

Comment: Anyone can get a /48 (65536 /64s) per the RIR IPv6 rules. Most providers will give you a /56 or /52 without asking. You can go straight to your RIR and get a /48.  Hurricane Electric will give you a tunnel for free. There is absolutely no reason to have a single /64. Assuming 17 billion people in 2100 the current IPv6 global addresses (1/8 of the range) will allow for 2100 /48s per person.  There is no reason to live in address poverty.

Comment: 3. Subnet Prefix Considerations
An important part of an IPv4 addressing plan is deciding the length of each subnet prefix.  Unlike in IPv4, the IPv6 addressing architecture [RFC4291] specifies that all subnets using Globally Unique Addresses and ULAs always have the same prefix length of 64  bits.  (This also applies to the deprecated 6bone and site-local addresses.)

Answer (score 0):

First of course the general warning: using non-`/64` subnet sizes will break things. Your ISP should really give you a decent amount of address space to work with, like a `/48` or a `/56`. You can then route `/64`s out of that wherever you want.

Then you have to look at how your ISP gives you your current `/64`. If they route it to a LAN that is connected to your server's `eth0` interface then there is nothing much you can do except bridging or proxy-ND because you have to make it look like everything is directly connected to that LAN. Both methods have their own complications.

If you are bridging to a LAN managed by your ISP then you shouldn't run anything like `radvd` or `dhcpd` because you'll interfere with your ISP.

If you are using proxy-ND or your ISP routes the `/64` to your server (so you have a different IPv6 address on your server's interface to the ISP and the ISP routes the `/64` to that interface) then you should indeed run `radvd` and `dhcpd` but only on the internal interface, not towards your ISP.

Back to your RA+DHCPv6 setup because that part of your question is easy to answer. There are three things wrong with your `radvd` setup (so, yes, it matters a lot :)

First you cannot do SLAAC (StateLess Address Auto Configuration) on anything except a `/64` so you'll have to turn `AdvAutonomous` off. Then you have to tell the clients that a managed (stateful) DHCPv6 server is available so turn the `AdvManagedFlag` on. And the `route 2000::/3` is also unnecessary. You are advertising that you are the default gateway and this more-specific doesn't add anything useful.

```
interface eth1 {
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    AdvManagedFlag on;
    prefix 2a01:4f8:202:6106:acda::/80 {
        AdvOnLink on;
        AdvAutonomous off;
        AdvRouterAddr on;
    };
};
```